# C - Segmentation Fault while Creating Binary Tree Using recursion

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I was trying to write a simple program of creating a binary tree using pointers in C , but I am unable to find the problem with this code. 
I am receiving Segmentation Fault on the second insertion.

The program takes input of five numbers and then creates a binary tree using the array input.Sample run :

Here is the output of the program

> Enter 5 elements :
>
> 45 78 89 32 46
>
> In generateBST
>
> In insert Going to right sub tree
>
> In insert
>
> Segmentation fault

Please help me resolve this error. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node * lst;
    struct node * rst;
}Node;

void printBST(Node *root){
    puts("In printBST");
    if(root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    printBST(root->lst);
    printf(" %d ", root->value);
    printBST(root->rst);
}

void insert(Node **root, int element){
    puts("In insert");
    if((*root)->value > element){
        puts("Going to left sub tree");
        insert(&(*root)->lst ,element);
    } else if ((*root)->value < element) {
        puts("Going to right sub tree");
        insert(&(*root)->rst ,element);
    } else {
        puts("Creating a new node to insert");
        Node * newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->value = element;
        newNode->lst = NULL;
        newNode->rst = NULL;
        (*root) = newNode;
    }
}

Node* generateBST(int *elements, int n){
    puts("In generateBST");
    int i =0;
    Node * root = NULL;
    root = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    root->value = *(elements);
    root->lst = NULL;
    root->rst = NULL;
    for(i=1; i < n; i++){
        insert(&root, *(elements+i));
    }
    return root;
}

int main(){
    Node * root = NULL;
    int i = 0, element, *elements ;
    elements = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    puts("Enter 5 elements : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        scanf("%d",&element);
        elements[i] = element;
    }
    root = generateBST(elements,5);
    printBST(root);
    //deallocBST(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry dint use gdb, dont know how to, but yeah now am trying to run it with gdb . ..

Comment: @FurquanAhmed, you don't know how to use gdb. Well, then it's about the right moment to start learning it. It's a great time saver.

Comment: Can't really help you without gdb's input...

Comment: I thought casting is good, otherwise it prompts warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found your problem using gdb. You have an error on line 22.
The problem is that you don't check whether root is null or not which is problem for the insertion of the first element.

To run your program through gdb simply compile and run using:

```
g++ -g YourPorgram.cpp
gdb a.out
run
```

When the programs stops (segfaultor other problems) type:

```
bt
```

Comment: An upvote for debugging which OP should have done  :)

Answer (score 8):

In insert, if `*root` is null you get a segmentation fault when you dereference `(*root)->value`. You need to handle that case:

```
void insert(Node **root, int element){
    puts("In insert");
    if (*root == null || (*root)->value == element) {
        puts("Creating a new node to insert");
        Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->value = element;
        newNode->lst = NULL;
        newNode->rst = NULL;
        (*root) = newNode;
    } else if((*root)->value > element){
        puts("Going to left sub tree");
        insert(&(*root)->lst ,element);
    } else {  /* (*root)->value < element */
        puts("Going to right sub tree");
        insert(&(*root)->rst ,element);
    }
}
```